# Extjs Toolbar crash, extjs 4.2.1, Chrome, Windows

Tags: javascript, extjs, extjs4

Verry weird bug when developing a application. The toolbar dissapears whenever i add a button to it. The code is as follows:

```
Ext.create('Ext.toolbar.Toolbar', {
      renderTo: document.body,
      width   : window,
      height: window,
      items: [
                        {
              xtype    : 'textfield',
              name     : 'field1',
              emptyText: 'enter search term'
          },
          '-',
         {
               xtype    : 'button'
           // icon: 'img/cross_cursor.gif'}
           }
      ]})
```

No errors encountered

Answer (score 0):

Height and width point to `window` object. Give your toolbar an explicit width or no dimensions whatsoever. See https://fiddle.sencha.com/#fiddle/cfn